# Generate c++ tags with ctags for files without suffix

Tags: c++, ctags

I have a problem with the generation of c++-tagfiles with ctags. Unfortunately, in our project we have many header-files without any file-suffix and I do not get any tags for these files when I work with

```
ctags -R  −−language−force=C++ --sort=yes --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --tag-relative=yes
```

I thought that '−−language−force=C++' would do the trick, but thats wrong. I have also tried to add the

```
-h "+."
```

flag as it is mentioned in the documentation but still - no tags for files without any suffixes.

Can anybody help out?

Markus

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

`ctags -h=".h,."  --language-force="c++" -R *`

It was important that `-h` and `--language-force` was given on the same line!